# Spatial and Non Spatial join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have a shapefile with a number of weed control blocks as polygons. They each have a unique block id number.
I am trying to join a non spatial csv file which has multiple entries for each block over 10yr period.
I have tried using Make a Query table but instead of coming up with 411 entries it comes up with over 19,000

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: How many rows in the CSV? It sounds like you're joining the CSV to the weed control blocks and returning one row for each row in the CSV (possibly limited to only the records in the CSV that match the weed control blocks). What are you trying to do with the join?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a feature class file which are weed control polygons. I am trying to enter historical weed control data which has been given to me in a spreadsheet. I have tidyed it up and turned it into a csv file. There are 313 lines rows in the csv file. The historical control records will then be entered into a corporate gdb

Comment: Import the CSV into a database as a table, text files can do silly things, if you have Access you can use that to import the CSV into a personal geodatabase (create in catalog first) as a table then you can see it in ArcCatalog. From the sounds of it you don't have enough records for each polygon; is there duplication in the CSV at all?

Comment: I have imported the csv file into a geodatabase through Catalog. In some cases there wont be any records for some of the polygons. There isnt any duplication that I can find in the csv file, they are multiple entries of record sheets for some of the polygons but they all differ either by date, species time etc.

Comment: Now try the join; It is an attribute join isn't it? Field in polygons matches field in table.. are you joining polygons to table or table to polygons?

Comment: I had tried the polygon to table using attributes and it only showed one entry per block where there are multiple entries by block. Ill try table to Polygon and see.

Comment: With the join the input features are preserved, so each polygon joins to the first matching record in the table when you join Polygon-Table. If you join the other way around Table-Polygon then each row in the table will show the matching polygon. Should you need to join Polygon-Table and see *every match* then refer Stephens' answer about relates; joins are always 1:1 (one row to one row).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a Join, try creating a [Relationship](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002n000000).

This will allow you to select one or more weed control blocks, then use the relationship to select the associated records in the table.

Note that you may need to import your CSV file into a geodatabase in order to use the relationship, which relies on a unique Object ID for each record.